# MongoDB replica set - Secondary repeatedly goes down

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, replicaset

I'm trying to set up a MongoDB replica set on my Kubernetes cluster but the Secondary member keeps restarting after a few seconds.

Here's a couple of things but might be useful to know:

- The Mongo server (and client) version is `4.0.6`
- I'm using the official helm [mongodb-replicaset](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb-replicaset) chart to set up the replica set and the only custom setting I'm using is `enableMajorityReadConcern: false`
- Oplog size is configured to ~1228MB (only 4.7 used)
- It happens with both a Primary-Secondary arch and with a PSA architecture where the Arbiter dies repeatedly like the Secondary member whilst the Primary is always up and running
- This happens both on my minikube and on a staging cluster on GCP with plenty of free resources (I'm deploying this with no resources limits, see right below for cluster status)

Staging cluster status (4 nodes):

```
NAME                               CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
gke-staging-pool-1-********-****   551m         28%    3423Mi          60%       
gke-staging-pool-1-********-****   613m         31%    3752Mi          66%       
gke-staging-pool-1-********-****   960m         49%    2781Mi          49%       
gke-staging-pool-1-********-****   602m         31%    3590Mi          63%
```

At the moment since the Primary seems to be able to stay up and running I managed to keep the cluster live by removing the `votes` to all members but the primary. This way Mongo doesn't relinquish the primary for not being able to see a majority of the set and my app can still do writes.

If I turn the `logLevel` to `5` on the Secondary the only error I get is this:

```
2019-04-02T15:11:42.233+0000 D EXECUTOR [replication-0] Executing a task on behalf of pool replication
2019-04-02T15:11:42.233+0000 D EXECUTOR [replication-0] Not reaping because the earliest retirement date is 2019-04-02T15:12:11.980+0000
2019-04-02T15:11:42.233+0000 D NETWORK  [RS] Timer received error: CallbackCanceled: Callback was canceled
2019-04-02T15:11:42.235+0000 D NETWORK  [RS] Decompressing message with snappy
2019-04-02T15:11:42.235+0000 D ASIO     [RS] Request 114334 finished with response: { cursor: { nextBatch: [], id: 46974224885, ns: "local.oplog.rs" }, ok: 1.0, operationTime: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), $replData: { term: 11536, lastOpCommitted: { ts: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), t: 11536 }, lastOpVisible: { ts: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), t: 11536 }, configVersion: 666752, replicaSetId: ObjectId('5c8a607380091703c787b3ff'), primaryIndex: 0, syncSourceIndex: -1 }, $oplogQueryData: { lastOpCommitted: { ts: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), t: 11536 }, lastOpApplied: { ts: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), t: 11536 }, rbid: 1, primaryIndex: 0, syncSourceIndex: -1 }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } } }
2019-04-02T15:11:42.235+0000 D EXECUTOR [RS] Received remote response: RemoteResponse --  cmd:{ cursor: { nextBatch: [], id: 46974224885, ns: "local.oplog.rs" }, ok: 1.0, operationTime: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), $replData: { term: 11536, lastOpCommitted: { ts: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), t: 11536 }, lastOpVisible: { ts: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), t: 11536 }, configVersion: 666752, replicaSetId: ObjectId('5c8a607380091703c787b3ff'), primaryIndex: 0, syncSourceIndex: -1 }, $oplogQueryData: { lastOpCommitted: { ts: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), t: 11536 }, lastOpApplied: { ts: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), t: 11536 }, rbid: 1, primaryIndex: 0, syncSourceIndex: -1 }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } } }
2019-04-02T15:11:42.235+0000 D EXECUTOR [replication-5] Executing a task on behalf of pool replication
2019-04-02T15:11:42.235+0000 D REPL     [replication-5] oplog fetcher read 0 operations from remote oplog
2019-04-02T15:11:42.235+0000 D EXECUTOR [replication-5] Scheduling remote command request: RemoteCommand 114336 -- target:foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset-0.foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset.foodchain.svc.cluster.local:27017 db:local expDate:2019-04-02T15:11:47.285+0000 cmd:{ getMore: 46974224885, collection: "oplog.rs", batchSize: 13981010, maxTimeMS: 50, term: 11536, lastKnownCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), t: 11536 } }
2019-04-02T15:11:42.235+0000 D ASIO     [replication-5] startCommand: RemoteCommand 114336 -- target:foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset-0.foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset.foodchain.svc.cluster.local:27017 db:local expDate:2019-04-02T15:11:47.285+0000 cmd:{ getMore: 46974224885, collection: "oplog.rs", batchSize: 13981010, maxTimeMS: 50, term: 11536, lastKnownCommittedOpTime: { ts: Timestamp(1554217899, 1), t: 11536 } }
2019-04-02T15:11:42.235+0000 D EXECUTOR [replication-5] Not reaping because the earliest retirement date is 2019-04-02T15:12:11.980+0000
2019-04-02T15:11:42.235+0000 D NETWORK  [RS] Timer received error: CallbackCanceled: Callback was canceled
2019-04-02T15:11:42.235+0000 D NETWORK  [RS] Compressing message with snappy
2019-04-02T15:11:42.235+0000 D NETWORK  [RS] Timer received error: CallbackCanceled: Callback was canceled
2019-04-02T15:11:42.235+0000 D NETWORK  [RS] Timer received error: CallbackCanceled: Callback was canceled
2019-04-02T15:11:42.235+0000 D NETWORK  [RS] Timer received error: CallbackCanceled: Callback was canceled
```

Given the network error I verified if all members could connect to each other and they can (it's explicitly showed in the logs of all three members).

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

```
foodchain_rs:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "foodchain_rs",
    "date" : ISODate("2019-04-02T15:35:02.640Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(11536),
    "syncingTo" : "",
    "syncSourceHost" : "",
    "syncSourceId" : -1,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "optimes" : {
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1554219299, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(11536)
        },
        "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1554219299, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(11536)
        },
        "appliedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1554219299, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(11536)
        },
        "durableOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1554219299, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(11536)
        }
    },
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset-0.foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset.foodchain.svc.cluster.local:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 4376,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1554219299, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(11536)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2019-04-02T15:34:59Z"),
            "syncingTo" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1554214927, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2019-04-02T14:22:07Z"),
            "configVersion" : 666752,
            "self" : true,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset-1.foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset.foodchain.svc.cluster.local:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 10,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1554219299, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(11536)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1554219299, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(11536)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2019-04-02T15:34:59Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2019-04-02T15:34:59Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2019-04-02T15:35:01.747Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2019-04-02T15:35:01.456Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
            "syncingTo" : "foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset-0.foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset.foodchain.svc.cluster.local:27017",
            "syncSourceHost" : "foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset-0.foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset.foodchain.svc.cluster.local:27017",
            "syncSourceId" : 0,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 666752
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1554219299, 1),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1554219299, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
foodchain_rs:PRIMARY> rs.printReplicationInfo()
configured oplog size:   1228.8701171875MB
log length start to end: 1646798secs (457.44hrs)
oplog first event time:  Thu Mar 14 2019 14:08:51 GMT+0000 (UTC)
oplog last event time:   Tue Apr 02 2019 15:35:29 GMT+0000 (UTC)
now:                     Tue Apr 02 2019 15:35:34 GMT+0000 (UTC)
foodchain_rs:PRIMARY> db.getReplicationInfo()
{
    "logSizeMB" : 1228.8701171875,
    "usedMB" : 4.7,
    "timeDiff" : 1646838,
    "timeDiffHours" : 457.46,
    "tFirst" : "Thu Mar 14 2019 14:08:51 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
    "tLast" : "Tue Apr 02 2019 15:36:09 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
    "now" : "Tue Apr 02 2019 15:36:11 GMT+0000 (UTC)"
}
foodchain_rs:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "foodchain_rs",
    "version" : 666752,
    "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
    "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault" : true,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset-0.foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset.foodchain.svc.cluster.local:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset-1.foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset.foodchain.svc.cluster.local:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
            "votes" : 0
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : 100,
        "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1,
        "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        },
        "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("5c8a607380091703c787b3ff")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was a too short [electionTimeoutMillis](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/replica-configuration/#rsconf.settings.electionTimeoutMillis) setting.

> Lower values result in faster failover, but increased sensitivity to primary node or network slowness or spottiness.

In my case it was set to `100ms` and that wasn't enough time for my Secondary to find the Primary member so it was unable to sync and thus unavailable.

I think it's also worth noting that the process was not being killed. The `mongod` PID was always `1` and the uptime showed in `top` did not coincide with the uptime showed in the `rs.status()` mongo shell.

What I was doing was monitoring the Secondary uptime via the mongo shell like this:

```
watch -n 1.0 "kubectl -n foodchain exec -it foodchain-backend-mongodb-replicaset-0 -- mongo --eval='rs.status().members.map(m => m.uptime)'"
```

With that command I could see that the Secondary uptime was never longer than 10s so I assumed it was restarting itself or being OOM killed or something, instead I think it was trying to fire an election but didn't have the votes to do so and went silent on restarting. In fact what I think it really confused me was the lack of information in that regard despite having set the `logLevel` to `5`.